# Generating uniformly distributed random numbers within a range in C++

Tags: c++

I know there are similar questions.
But mine has different settings.

- Have to use `rand()`
- Have to use `srand()` to take a seed from user input
- Only using standard library

I don't know if it's possible to get uniformly distributed random numbers, do I have to use the `random` library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C++ standard mostly defers to the C standard when it comes to the heritage functions like `rand()` and `srand()`.

Unfortunately, there is *nothing* in the C standard about `rand()` delivering uniform distribution. In fact, it states in a footnote (my emphasis):

> There are ***no guarantees as to the quality of the random sequence produced*** and some implementations are known to produce sequences with distressingly non-random low-order bits. Applications with particular requirements should use a generator that is known to be sufficient for their needs.

If you want specific properties for your random numbers, you really should be using the C++ stuff in `<random>` (yes, I know you appear to have discounted that but you may have to make a trade-off: either use them or have no guarantee of a specific distribution).

Comment: But is that possible (with `rand()`) if we do some mathematical operation? I'm not a math major so I have no idea.

Comment: @shidangai, nor am I. Perhaps it would be a good idea to defer to someone who is more likely to understand the math: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3533/converting-non-uniform-distribution-to-a-uniform-distribution . Or if, as like me, you get a headache from reading that, use `<random>` since it was put together by people who understand it :-)